# __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)...im receiving this error may be due to a NoneType user model

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

[image: error in admin panel]I'm getting this error, in admin panel other than this the website is working fine.

Here is my forms.py[image: forms.py]

Here is models.py[image: models.py]

These are in views.py[image: view1]
And this is for new user registration[image: new user view]

I think the error is happening because the **order** model is receiving a NoneType **customer** as a foreign key.
But I don't know how to solve this problem.
I'm new to django please help me out.

Comment: Please do not upload images of code / errors, [edit] your question and add them as text formatted as code. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: To answer your question `if self.name` you return something in that condition is true but what if that condition is false? You are returning nothing in that case. Plus something that is meant to be the string representation being nullable is not a great string representation.

Comment: Yes sir, I've checked the self.name returned the customer name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
 def __str__(self):
    if self.name:
        return self.name
    else:
        return self.email
```

you have to return at least something